# Formalism for Unit Consistency

Tags: units

I was thinking about how the propagation constant for Transmission Lines looks like this:
${\displaystyle \gamma =\alpha +i\beta}$ , and here the units for $\beta$ is $\frac{radians}{meter}$ and the units for $\alpha$ is $\frac{neper}{meter}$, I understand 'why' this is done, because the $\beta$ in reality signifies phase constant of the wave so it is a measure of $\frac{angle}{length}$, and $\alpha$ represents the attenuation constant so it is a measure of $\frac{attenuation}{length}$, and we are technically allowed to add them since Np and Rad are both unitless measures.

I was wondering if there is a more formal justification or reason as to why we do this? More generally is there some more rigorous structure for all of the "rules" of units?

Comment: There is a super rigorous treatment by mathematician Terry Tao on his blog: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/. But it boils down to essentially what you said... $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both have dimensions of 1/length so you can add them freely.

Comment: this is really helpful, thank you!